# ANGULAR: array filter by clicking an button doesn't work

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, filter

I am trying to filter my array by using modula on the id by clicking multiple buttons. I tried using pipe but it was recommended using just the .filter(). I don't know what to do, i watched many video's online but they get too complicated or i always get some error that they don't have. Or am i just going in the wrong direction for a simple onclick filter. I am quite a beginner to angular.

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { StreamService } from '../stream.service';
import { Stream } from '../stream';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-discover',
  templateUrl: './discover.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./discover.component.scss']
})
export class DiscoverComponent implements OnInit {
  streams!: Stream[];
  
  constructor(private streamService: StreamService) { 
    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getStreams();
  }

  getStreams(){
    this.streamService.getStream().subscribe((data =>{
      this.streams = data;
      console.log(this.streams);
    }))
  }

  sortBack(){
    this.streams.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
  }


  filterIsUneven(){
    this.streams.filter(stream => stream.id % 3)
  };
  
  

}
```

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="buttons">
    <button (click) = "filterIsUneven()"> Games </button>
    <button> Music </button>
    <button> Esports </button>
    <button> IRL </button>
    <button>Back</button>
  </div>

  <div class="streams" *ngFor="let stream of streams">
    <h3>{{stream.id}}</h3>
    <h3>{{stream.title}}</h3>
    <img src="{{stream.thumbnailUrl}}">
  </div>

</div>
```

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Stream } from './stream';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
 
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StreamService{

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getStream():Observable<Stream[]>{
  return this.http.get<Stream[]>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1/photos");
  }

getLiveStream(id:number):Observable<Stream[]> {
  const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1/photos?id=${id}`;
  return this.http.get<Stream[]>(url);
  }
}
```

Comment: `filter` creates a new array because it is an immutable action. It _does not mutate_ the existing one. Change your `filterIsUneven` method to: `this.streams = this.streams.filter(stream => stream.id % 3)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering, but not assigning the result, you should do this:

```
filterIsUneven(){
  this.streams = this.streams.filter(stream => stream.id % 3)
};
```

The issue is that it is a permanent filter, you cannot come back to the initial list. What you can do then is making a new list:

```
getStreams(){
  this.streamService.getStream().subscribe((data =>{
    this.filteredStreams = data;
    this.streams = data;
    console.log(this.streams);
  }))
}

filterIsUneven(){
  this.filteredStreams = this.streams.filter(stream => stream.id % 3)
};
```

and then, use `filteredStreams` in the HTML instead of `streams`

Comment: Sorry, I was not copy pasting your answer (it was not yet there) . But the solution was so obvious that we even came up with the same name for the variable.

Comment: @mrak That's the power of good practices haha

Answer (score 0):

"The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function."

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

So you have to overwrite the `this.streams` property:

```
  filterIsUneven(){
    this.streams = this.streams.filter(stream => stream.id % 3)
  };
```

I guess this will work for this case, but it is not reversible.
You could introduce a new property `this.filteredStreams`, initialise it with the original values and project your filters and use it to display in the `ngFor` loop.